# Separate cells content into rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is a requirement where I want to separate out content from a cell, Can someone guide me on the possibility and approach to achieve it.

Source Table :

```
ID | Log
____________________
1  | Status : New 
   | Assignment : 1
   | Priority : Low
_____________________
2  | Status : In Progress
   | Impact : High
```

Target Table :

```
ID | Key       | Value
____________________
1  | Status    | New 
1  | Assignment| 1
1  | Priority  | Low
2  | Status    | In Progress
2  | Impact    | High
```

Comment: for row `Assignment : 1` what is the value for `ID` ? `NULL` ? If it `NULL`, how do you know the ID suppose to be 1 or 2 ? is there another column that can identify this ?

Comment: ID is 1 for status assignment and Priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [Log] is multi-line delimited with CRLF

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,[Key]   = ltrim(rtrim(left(RetVal,charindex(':',RetVal)-1)))
      ,[Value] = ltrim(rtrim(substring(RetVal,charindex(':',RetVal)+1,len(RetVal))))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[log],char(10),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as B1
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Key         Value
1   Status      New
1   Assignment  1
1   Priority    Low
2   Status      In Progress
2   Impact      High
```

Comment: Thank you Sir.. I tried with this it seems not giving expected result.. lets say for ID 1; Status is going on Key column and remaining all content is going in values column.

Comment: It is delimited by CHAR(10) , new line character.. I mean I am able to do substr correctly using CHAR(10)

Comment: I assume CRLF so remove the "char(13)+" in the Cross Apply

Comment: @MayurRandive Updated. I removed char(13) from the delimiter

Comment: @MayurRandive Happy to help

Comment: If same i have to implement in Oracle then what all changes i have to do ?

Comment: @MayurRandive not an Oracle guy

Answer (score 1):

You can use following SQL script too,
But before using it you need to create a [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) on your database. I'm using one of the referred split functions

```
with tbl as (
    select 
        ID, Log, row_number() over (order by Log) as rn
    from sourceTable
)
select
    ID,
    max([Key]) as [Key],
    max([Value]) as [Value]
from (
    select
        ID,
        rn,
        case when sid = 1 then val else null end as [Key],
        case when sid = 2 then val else null end as [Value]
    from (
        select 
            tbl.ID, 
            tbl.rn, 
            s.id sid,
            val
        from tbl
        cross apply dbo.split(tbl.Log,':') s
    ) t
) t
group by ID, rn
order by ID, rn
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Comment: I tried this one .. which split function you are using ? In my case status is going in key section and remaining content is going in value section;

Comment: Link is here: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx for SPLIT UDF taking two input parameters one for input string @s nvarchar(max), the other one is the seperator character ":"  @splitChar nchar(1). It will return two rows for each splitted piece, 1st row is for key, and the second row is for the value.

Comment: Thank you very much